# Solr encoding URL with the character '&'

Tags: java, solr

I'm facing with a problem using Solr :

When the character '&' in my url is enconding ('%26'), that doesn't work :

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/LOREMIPSUM/select?q=shop_id:42+label_fr_str:LOL%26rows=20&indent=off

<result name="response" numFound="0" start="0">
```

But when it's not the case I have 4223 résuslts :

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/LOREMIPSUM/select?q=shop_id:42+label_fr_str:LOL&rows=20&indent=off

<result name="response" numFound="4223" start="0">
```

I'm a bit lost. Is there something to do with the request or with the configuration of Solr to resolve it? Or it's just not possible?

**EDIT :**

*The field defined in my schema.xml*

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField"
    positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
            generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1"
            catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
            generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0"
            catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

*The field decleration :*

```
<field name="label_fr_str" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

Comment: Can you show how you tokenize the data? Do you tokenize the query in the same way?

Comment: I'm using an UTF-8 encoding :  URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8"); (e.g. String query="shop_id:42+label_fr_str:LOL&rows=20").

Comment: It is interesting that in your example, one ampersand is encoded and another is not... Is there a difference in the way that the `rows` parameter is being added to your url versus how `indent` is being added. Also, since you are using java have you looked at SolrJ - http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj

Comment: I mean how is the field defined in your `schema.xml` config file

Comment: @PaigeCook you're right in my example all characters should be encoded. But in this case I juste changed one character to show up the problem.

Comment: What container are you hosting Solr in?

Comment: @PaigeCook I'm using both Jetty and Tomcat

Comment: @Qwerky I added all the information in the subject of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I played around a little bit with the query-string and I was able to reproduce a similar behavior. I think the root of the issue is that if you encode the ampersand for the next parameter after your `q` parameter, Solr interprets this as part of the query and not as a query-string parameter.

Based on the example of encoding you provided in the comments, you are mixing query parameters (rows in this case) with the query itself. I would recommend keeping these separate. Have you considering using the [SolrJ](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj) client. I realize you may not want to use the SolrJ client, but I think you should at least consider using the [ClientUtils](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/branches/lucene_solr_4_2/solr/solrj/src/java/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/util/ClientUtils.java?view=markup) methods of it to assist you with properly building/encoding your urls.

Comment: Very thank you for your quick reply. I would like to use SolrJ and also highly recommend it. But unfortunately, for some political reasons I'm not allowed to use it. 

Again thank you for yours advises and the usefull link (ClientUtils).